# How to add space after '}' char in a big PHP string?

Tags: php, string, subst

I have a big .css file which is all coded inline. That makes it very inelegant and hard to find the elements accurately. I want to paste it into a PHP function which gives a space after each "{" bracket, cause if I would do it manually it would take me more time.

which function should I use?

Comment: You can paste your code in a beautifier online tool like  https://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/

Answer (score 1):

```
$input_data = str_replace('}', '} ', $input_data);
```

Comment: I'll test it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use `preg_replace` here:

```
$input = "p.a {
        font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
    }";
$output = preg_replace("/\{/", " {", $input);
echo $input . "\n";
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
p.a {
        font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
    }
p.a  {    <-- extra space here
        font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only interest is to add a space after all the "{", toy could easily use the following code:

```
$CSS = '.sample{
    padding: 10px;
}';
echo 'Old CSS code: '.$CSS.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

$cleanCSS = str_replace('{', '{ ', $css);
echo 'Clean CSS code: '.$cleanCSS;
```

This code prints:

```
Old CSS code: .sample{
    padding: 10px;
}

Clean CSS code: .sample {
    padding: 10px;
}
```